# How to set webbrowser media type to print in C#?

Tags: c#, browser

In the webbrowser control, I want to set the media type = print. So it will display the contents in print preview mode. Is this possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution it seems is redirect the request to some other server, which will fetch the original page and modify the css attributes to show print layout on the screen. This can be done by removing the screen css files and setting the attribute media="print" to media="screen".

Answer (score 0):

In google chrome (i use version 33 now) you can open developer tools by <kbd>F12</kbd> then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. in Emulation tab you can set `CSS media` to `print`.

Answer (score -1):

Simulate a print preview with CSS by setting the media property to print -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/print.css" media="print" />
```

[Creating print preview page dynamically in ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20100327161143/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/ferdous/articles/103175.aspx)

[Creating print preview page dynamically in ASP.NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13795/Creating-print-preview-page-dynamically-in-ASP-NET)

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10083542/open-the-print-preview-di.aspx

Comment: Is it possible to split the data pagewise like in MS word

Comment: I said how to do that in the C# Webbrowser control for any website.